# Cloud Function No Logging

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create a FCM when there is a change in my Firebase Realtime Database. The Cloud Function code is pasted below. So far no notifications are showing so I'm trying to see if the cloud function is correct. However, I'm not seeing the logs either on the Firebase console so debugging has been difficult. Can anyone provide insights why the logs are not showing? The deployment completed without issues.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config.firebase);


exports.notificationFCM = functions.database.ref('/chats/{userId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => { 
  const userId = context.params.userId;
      const payload = {
        notifiction: {
          title: `New message`,
          body: `Click to check your message!`,
          badge: `1`,
          sound: `default`
        }
        };
     
     const token = await admin.database()
    .ref(`tokens/${userId}`)
    .once('value');
  if (token.val().deviceToken != null) {
    console.log(userId);
    console.log('Sucess');
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token.val().deviceToken, payload);

  }
  else {
    console.log('No token avaliable');
    console.log(userId);
  }
});
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code that can potentially prevent the Cloud Function working correctly:

1. There is a typo in the way you declare the payload: `const payload = {notifiction:...` shall be `const payload = {notification:...` with an **a**.
2. Since v 1.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions you can no longer pass in `functions.config().firebase` when initializing. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin).

---

In addition you should return something in the `else` bloc, like:

```
  if (token.val().deviceToken != null) {
    //...
  }
  else {
    console.log('No token avaliable');
    console.log(userId);
    return null;
  }
```

and you should add a `try/catch` block in order to be able debug your code:

```
exports.notificationFCM = functions.database.ref('/chats/{userId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    try {
        // Your code
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks Renaud, I have made those changes. The console log shows: TypeError: token.val is not a function. 

Since I am using Firebase RTDB, token.val() should be a proper call, do you know what might be wrong here?

Comment: Mmmhhh... Indeed `token.val()` is the correct syntax and it should work... Are you sure you updated to a version of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions > 1.0? What do you see in your `package.json`file?

Comment: I updated the original post with the package.json file